# Unexpected closing curly brace } error

Tags: php, mysql, braces

I know this topic has been beaten into the ground, but I'm really stumped. I can't figure out why I'm getting an unexpected } error.

My problem is with a code snippet I've added to a Paypal credit card terminal script. It captures the form data into a MySql database so we can keep track of billing address information, etc. It works until I add an IF statement that is supposed to only send the data to MySQL if Paypal successfully successfully captures the card info. I want to do it this way because even if the form fails to capture the CC info, it will still be added to the database as if it were successful.

Here's the code. Again, it works until I add the `if($ack="SUCCESS")  {` and the corresponding closing brace at the end. If I remove the brace, I get an unexpected end error.

What is the error? In Notepad++ everything looks like it matches up.

```
if($ack="SUCCESS")  {   
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "dbpassword");
    if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_select_db("contributors", $con);
    $sql="INSERT INTO contributor_information (service, fname, lname, email, address, city, country, state, zip)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[service]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[zip]')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_close($con)
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after mysql_close($con)

Comment: And it should be if ($ack == "SUCCESS"), with a double equals

Comment: Also. PLEASE do not put $_POST in your query like that. It's bound to have all sorts of evilness in them. Use PDO parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semi-colon after `mysql_close($con)`.

You need quotes in your POST variables - $_POST['email'] and so on.

You need to run your POST variables through mysql_real_escape_string.

You need to use comparison instead of assignment ( `if($ack=="SUCCESS")` instead of `if($ack="SUCCESS")` )

Curly braces are the least of your worries, really.

Comment: Thanks. This snippet was copied and pasted from the W3C, so it's actually their errors. ;) Because I have no idea what I'm doing.

So why did it work without the semicolon before the if statement?

Comment: @Charles: That is because the last line of a program can be used without a semicolon. When you add the if statement then this code of line no longer last statement of program.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I've just ordered a PHP/MySql book, so I hope the next question I ask won't be such a basic one!

Answer (score 1):

add semicolon here

```
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `;` from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put a `;` after

```
mysql_close($con)
```

:)